# How to set background within the titled border?

Tags: java, swing, border

I have a JLabel that I do `setBackground(Color.WHITE)` and `setBorder(new CustomTitledBorder(Color.BLACK, "Some Text")`. The white background from the JLabel is outside of the border bounds. I tried looking around and found this solution:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TempFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TempFrame frame = new TempFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TempFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        var label = new MyLabel();
        label.setBounds(10, 10, 334, 65);
        getContentPane().add(label);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Click To Add Text");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("String");
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(127, 86, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }

    private class MyLabel extends JLabel {

        public MyLabel() {
            
            setOpaque(true);
            setBorder(new CustomTitledBorder(Color.BLACK, "Title Here"));
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            
        }

/* Here is where I am having the problem */
//      @Override
//      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//          var insets = this.getBorder().getBorderInsets(this);
//          g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//          g.fillRect(insets.left, insets.top, getWidth() - insets.left - insets.right,
//                  getHeight() - insets.top - insets.bottom);
//      }

    }

    private class CustomTitledBorder extends TitledBorder {

        public CustomTitledBorder(Color color, String title) {
            super(new LineBorder(color), title);
            
        }

    }
}
```

This is without modifying the `paintComponent()` method
[image: Without modifying paintComponent()]

This is what I want the `paintComponent()` method to do
[image]

If I try to add text to it using `setText("String");`, this is the result. I can see some of my other components too somehow overlapping each other in that corner
[image]

How do I make it so that it does not do that?

Comment: A LineBorder doesn't paint text. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. Post an [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Borders don’t have the ability to fill there background

Comment: @camickr I have added an example below of what I inteded to do and the results of it. I don't understand how modifying the paintComponent method would affect the setting text.

Comment: You still haven't posted an [mre]. You implemented the paintComponent(...) method incorrectly and have lost all the default painting of the label. You need to invoke super.paintComponent(..). It is responsible for: 1) making sure the the background of the component is painted and 2) it paints the text of the label.

Comment: @camickr if I call super.paintComponent(..) it gives the same output as the first example where the background goes out of bounds of the border.

Comment: @camickr I have edited the code and added more context, is this enough for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: `import advising.font.StandardFont;` Can you replicate the problem with default fonts available to other JREs? If not, I'd tend to assume it is a wonky font being used and that is something we cannot help with. Note also that we cannot compile and run the code. A lot of the benefit of preparing an MRE is that other people can run and test it, then play with the code to investigate and test solutions.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry I had forgotten that I have those fonts, which can be removed. Those fonts are just classes that extends from the default `Font` class, and in the constructor its `super(new Font("Roboto", Font.PLAIN, 12));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image provided it appears you want the background color of the parent panel to be used for the background of the border and provide a different background color for the remainder of the label.

So this means that you need to:

1. keep the label transparent so the background of the parent is first painted
2. paint the background of the label minus the area used by the Border
3. paint the text of the label

So your custom label class should be:

```
private class MyLabel extends JLabel
{
    public MyLabel()
    {
        //setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(new CustomTitledBorder(Color.BLACK, "Title Here"));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
        var insets = this.getBorder().getBorderInsets(this);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(insets.left, insets.top, getWidth() - insets.left - insets.right, getHeight() - insets.top - insets.bottom);

        super.paintComponent(g);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that is exactly what I was looking for. I thought that to paint a component it must do `setOpaque(true)` for the background to be displayed